# On img load open new tab Jquery NOT ON CLICK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a image on a page, when that image is loaded I want the page to open a new tab loading a URL which downloads a file, But i want to keep the current page opened. This is all done inside wordpress and i have a section for Jquery in the back-end. Not sure how to go about this....

I have this so far:

## Jquery

```
 $( "#link" ).ready(function() {
  window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank'); 

 });
```

## HTML

```
 <h2>Download to start shortly...</h2>


  <h4>If the download doesn’t start soon please click below to download the file.</h4>
  </br>
 <div style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5px;">
 <a href="MyDownloadLinkFromPlugIn"><img id="link" src="MyImageLink"    style="margin-bottom:30px;"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: How could you download `http://www.facebook.com` ?

Comment: its just the example, i have just realised that its asked me to accept pop up the code is working and loads the URL, but if i put the direct download link to the file, it doesnt work...

Comment: Have you tried `download` attribute of `<a>` element ?

Comment: I will update my question maybye its easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#link" ).ready(function() {

    window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
})
```

Comment: Try using window.open(), see i have updated my previous answer

Comment: @user1673498 maybe your browser is blocking pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code.

it will be fired when your selected image is loaded.

```
$("img_selector_tag").on("load", function() {
   alert("image loaded sucessfully");
      //you activity
       window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank'); 

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
});
```